# How do I move back to HTTP from HTTPS?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I recently 301 my URLS from HTTP to HTTPS using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But now I want to revert everything back as I changed my mind and broke everything.

I am using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

But it seems to only work on some pages.

How do I mage it work on all pages?

Comment: You may wish to try and stick with https and fix what you broke ;) instead of trying to go back, only to have to go forward again? If you have any kind of form inputs... https is being _encouraged_ now by google and such.

Comment: Actually I need to go back to HTTP because adsense revenue went down by 75%!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This helped me!